# How to lock device and turn on display using tap/slide

Tags: lock-screens

My phone's power button is messed up. So am looking for something which will help me lock my phone and turn it on using either tapping or sliding. The knock lock app is great for locking but doesn't wake the phone. Is there an app/something that I can install that will help me lock/unlock without using my phones power button ?

Details : 
Android version : 4.4.4 
Phone : Nexus 4
Although I dont know the pros and cons yet but I don't want to root my phone

Comment: I had a similar problem with my n4's power button, but after searching for everything, ended up repairing the phone. It won't cost more than 10$.

Comment: Yeah, you **need** to repair the power button. If the phone gets turned off or the battery runs out, only the physical power button can turn it back on.